# MySQL Array/List Of Items And Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a Users table. Every user can create one or more lists of movies.

So I searched a little bit and found an answer in Stack Overflow that the best way to create lists is to create A List Table With `List_Id` And `User_ID` Columns and a `ListEntry` Table With `List_ID` and `Movie_ID` Column.Then I retrieve list entries by running "`SELECT Movie_ID FROM ListEntry WHERE List_ID=x`"

My Question is this. When my site grows and I have over 1000 users where each one has 2-3 lists where every list has 50 movies, the ListEntry table may have over 100.000 Entries. Isn't that gonna slow down the database ? Is this the way most sites work ? any better way of doing this ?

Comment: 100k entries is not so huge number for databases, but you should optimize your query, put the right indexes and narrow your search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are NOT going to store IDs of movies as anything but int(11) or probably less than in(11) - I am pretty sure there is no need for THAT many movies :} - the table will be "big" in amount of rows, but not big in amount of data.

MySQL is very efficient at locating and sorting values that have a small key length, i.e. your Movie_ID and User_ID will be two small keys ( int(11) or similar ), so their JOIN will be also small and done fairly quickly.

Anyway, I wouldn't worry about this, I have tables that have more than 10^8 (100,000,000) records if they are properly indexed and have good keys, MySQL has no difficulty handling it.

Answer (score 1):

100,000 entries? MySQL isn't even going to feel it - and neither will you. Come back when you have in excess of 10 million.

Answer (score 1):

Databases are designed to handle big loads of data. **With proper indexing** DBs can hold billions of records in a table.

Answer (score 1):

These number of rows inside a table won't be a problem for your MySql Server if the entries are well indexed. Some nice tips about the MySql performance can be found [here](http://phpmagazin.de/10-Tipps-zur-MySQL-Performance-058286.html). This is a german site with two (english) presentations about MySql performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoDB. It is schemaless. You can have list inside a document. (table)